# How do I get a users response in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How do I get the users response from a question asked to the user and display the response in fulfillment?

---

**Example:**
**Google Assistant:** *What is your name?*

**User:** *My name is Yuri Alves*

**Google Assistant:** *Hello, Yuri Alves*

Comment: Complete [this Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0)

Comment: @sai.raj Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to achieve this:

- Setup an intent with the response `What is your name?`
- Setup a follow-up intent, with phrases `My name is Yuri Alves, I am Yuri
  Alves` etc
- Make an entity `name_entity` for recognizing the first name and last name
- Mark the entity as `required`
- Give prompt `What is your name?`
- In the response print `Hello, $name_entity`
  [image: entity bases approach]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I think that will be very helpful

Comment: glad i could help, post your issues if any after you try this.